# Set JsonProperty or XMLElement localname using Open API

Tags: json, annotations, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have generated model from Open API spec. However, I need to annotate some fields with JsonProperty or XmlElement to map fields that have different name in the JSON/XML object they are being mapped to.

For example, in my POJO I want to to say "prop_one" but I want Json to have a corresponding field named as "prop_of_json_one_arb". I was previously using JsonProperty but now I have to auto-generate the models using open-api.

Is there any way I can do it using open-api generator (for java)?